# Create an envelope without sending an email to signer

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on a C#.net website and using DuoSecurity services to request electronic signatures. I want the users to sign the documents trough my web site so I decided to use the embedded signing feature.

To use this feature, you first need to create an envelope, but while creating an envelope I'm required to enter the signer's email address so DocuSign sends him an email with a link to the document, but I don't want this email to be sent.

To make it short, is there any way to create a DocuSign envelope without having DocuSign send an email to the signer? (I don't mind entering the signer's email, I have all the required information, it's just that for security purposes I don't want the end-user to receive the document URL trough email).

If not, is there any way to use the embedded signing feature without creating an envelope (I doubt it, but I really need a way to upload a document to DocuSign **without** them sending an email to the signer).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The system will not send them an email if you are using Embedding functionality.  To make use of Embedding and generate a URL token for a given envelope you need to set the **clientUserId** property for your recipients.

When the clientUserId property is present and its value is not null no email is sent to the recipient (only the envelope complete email gets sent once signing is done, but that is configurable).  Basically the only thing you have to remember with embedding is that you set the *clientUserId* property for your recipients at the time they are added to the envelope, then when you are request a URL token you need to reference the same email, name, and clientUserId combination.

You're two best resources on this are the Embedding API Walkthroughs (see the bottom 3):

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthroughs

And the DocuSign Dev Center page on Embedding functionality:

[Features -> Embedding](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign)

Comment: Do you know what function needs to be called to request a URL token using the same email, name, and clientUserId. I can't find any methods that have clientUserId as a param. My goal is to create an envelope without sending an e-mail so I set the clientUserId of the recipients. Now I would like my system to send a custom e-mail/sms message with a link for signing. What is the best way to generate this link?

Comment: Since you are creating the "Recipient View" when signing a document in embedded style the request is located off of the `EnvelopeViews` resource.  The call you need to make (after creating an envelope with an embedded recipient) is the [EnvelopeViews: createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient) API.  See the code walkthrough here [Sign From Your App](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/signing-from-your-app)

Comment: @Ergin is there a way to not include signer email in the `TemplateRole` when adding a signer for the template in embedded signing?